# Update oracle cluster nodelist on remote node with powershell

Tags: powershell

Recently I'm trying update a cluster node list on remote node, but don't know how to write this kind of command. Hope someone can let me know if this is operable.

The command is like:

```
$ORACLE_HOME\oui\bin\setup -updateNodelist ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME "CLUSTER_NODES={node_list}" CRS=TRUE -silent
```

I hope to pass params `$oracle_home` and `$node_list` to this function. Seems `$ORACLE_HOME\oui\bin\setup` is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with PowerShell and command lines, just run the setup.exe like this in Command Prompt(cmd.exe).

Following is the example if your ORACLE_HOME is C:\app\orauser\grid\

Also, update "node1,node2,node3,node4" to whatever your nodesname.

```
C:\app\orauser\grid\setup.exe -updateNodeList -local ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\orauser\grid -defaultHomeName "CLUSTER_NODES={node1,node2,node3,node4}" CRS=TRUE -silent
```